# Magento 2.4.3-p1 Braintree compilation issue

Tags: magento2.4.3

**I am having difficulties getting Magento 2.4.3-p1 to work when the Braintree module is enabled.**

[image]

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Ébano here, from Signifyd support for the Magento official extension. This is a known bug on version 4.3.3 of the Signifyd_Connect extension when installed on Magento 2.4.x. We're working on a fix for the next release.

Meanwhile, as a quick fix,  you can remove the Plugin/Braintree/Gateway/Validator/GeneralResponseValidator.php file and it's reference in etc/di.xml. This file has no use on Magento 2.4, only on Magento 2.3, that's why it's safe to remove it on 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

First Update the Braintree Module using the composer command and after that the issue will gets resolved Because the constructor classes will gets updated with the latest version and after that you can run the compilation without getting any error.

Comment: I am also updating Braintree Module using via composer command. But still occur error.

Comment: Ok, have you installed the updated module Signifyd_Connect.Update this Module and then check the compilation again. If its not fixed then remove the contructor argument Magento/Braintree/Gateway/SubjectReader From the php file Signyfyd/Connect/Plugin/Braintree/Gateway/Validator/GeneralResponseValidator.php